# GCDAsyncSocket write timeout does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

I am trying to set a timeout on write operations when using GCDAsyncSocket. The code is pretty simple and is the following.

```
[iAsyncSocket writeData:bytesToSend withTimeout:3.0 tag:0];
```

Then I disable the Internet connection on my Mac and wait for write timeout to occur, but nothing happens. I don't get a disconnection with a `GCDAsyncSocketWriteTimeoutError` error as I should.

I have also validated that my server stops, as expected, receiving the messages after I turn off the Internet connection.

I have looked inside the source code and I have found out that the writeTimer, that is responsible for firing a write timeout event, is always cancelled (function `endCurrentWrite` is called). Tracing back to where the timer is cancelled, I ended up at the following line of code.

```
ssize_t result = write(socketFD, buffer, (size_t)bytesToWrite);
```

The write system call always returns the total number of bytes that I am sending, as if the socket manages to send the data although there is no Internet connection. Is this logical?

Has anyone come up with the same problem or seen similar behaviour? Or has anyone managed to set a write timeout for a GCDAsyncSocket?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The kernel buffers the socket data. From the sender's view, the data *is* written.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. I suspected that something like that is happening.